# Percentages in SAS (FREQ, TABULATE?)

Tags: sas, percentage

I have a data set of line-by-line student information, ex:

1234   Fall 2013    International 
2234   Fall 2013    Domestic 
2234   Fall 2013    Domestic 
2235   Fall 2013    International 
7234   Fall 2014    International 
7234   Fall 2014    Domestic 
7234   Fall 2014    Domestic 
7235   Fall 2014    International 
8234   Spring 2013    International 
8234   Spring 2013    Domestic 
8234   Spring 2013    Domestic 
8235   Spring 2013    International 
9234   Spring 2014    International 
9234   Spring 2014    Domestic 
9234   Spring 2014    Domestic 
9235   Spring 2014    International

The data above repersents ID, term, and citizenship.  I have used proc freq and tabulate to try to get percentages, but I keep getting overall percentages of the entire data set.  I want the percentages per term, i.e. the sum of the percents of Fall 2013 should be 2 items (International and Domestic) and equal 100% by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You need `rowpctn` or `colpctn` in tabulate.

```
data have;
  input 
  id semester $ year origin :$15.
  ;

  datalines;
1234 Fall 2013 Domestic 
2234 Fall 2013 Domestic 
2234 Fall 2013 Domestic 
2235 Fall 2013 International 
7234 Fall 2014 International 
7234 Fall 2014 Domestic 
7234 Fall 2014 Domestic 
7235 Fall 2014 International 
8234 Spring 2013 International 
8234 Spring 2013 Domestic 
8234 Spring 2013 Domestic 
8235 Spring 2013 International 
9234 Spring 2014 International 
9234 Spring 2014 Domestic 
9234 Spring 2014 Domestic 
9235 Spring 2014 International 
;;;;
run;

proc tabulate data=have;
  class semester year origin;
  tables semester*year, origin*(n rowpctn);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked great.  Is there a way to format the percentages to two decimal places.  I have tried:

tables 'Start Date'n, KYResident*(n rowpctn)*F=8.2;

It's not working.